# Rails 3 Image upload form submitting with http instead of AJAX

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, html, jquery

I am working on a form to submit it by AJAX instead of http. 
This is the form :

```
    <%= form_for(:image, :remote => true, :url => {:controller=> 'questions',:action => 'upload'},:multipart => true) do |f| %>

    <%= f.file_field :image, :onchange => "$(this).parents('form').submit();"  %>

    <% end %>
```

I have set the `:remote => true`  option above and submitting the form with an `onchange` event . I have the following code in controller :

```
def upload

     if request.xhr?
        @image = Image.new(params[:image])
        @image.save

            respond_to do |format|
                format.js { render :layout=>false }
           end
     else
           render :text => 'Request Wasnt AJAX'
     end
end
```

My action renders the text everytime , the request does not seem to be AJAX style despite the remote tag being set (it appears correctly even in the final HTML). I can't figure out where I am going wrong with this . I have tested it in the latest browser version of FF and Chrome , so I don't think it's a browser issue. Any ideas ?

**Update** : I did some more debugging attempts . The issue is with the file field , if I replace the file field with text field , the request is AJAX (everything else remaining same) . But with a file field it always sends a non AJAX request.

**Note : Overall objective is to upload an image via AJAX request, with the response rendering nothing, no HTML, no redirection, no reload of the page.**

Comment: Do you have both `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs` in your application.js or other included JS file?

Comment: Hey , yes . And I did some more testing . The issue is with the file field , if I replace the file field with text field , the request is AJAX (everything else remaining same) . But with a file field it always sends a non AJAX request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it to work by installing the Remotipart gem . To upload image files using ajax form submission , this is the only way . Find the git here :https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart

Answer (score 1):

JQuery form.sumbit()  submits a form the normal way (Not Ajax). You have to do it differently:

```
$('#submitButton').click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some-url',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
              // ... do something with the data...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Not when :remote => true is set in rails . Please read the update . It works fine when the form field is text , fails specifically for image . Also uploading images through an ajax function like above is complicated without using a plugin.