# Rails 5: Remote form failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a form for create **products** in my rails app:

```
= form_for product, url: url, method: :post, html: { class: 'product-form' }, remote: true do |f|

  .row
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-6
      .form-group.required
        = f.label :name
        = f.text_field :name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control'
    .col-xs-12.col-sm-6
      .form-group.required
        = f.label :price
        .input-group
          .input-group-addon $
          = f.number_field :price, class: 'form-control'

  .row
    .col-xs-12
      .form-group
        = f.label :description
        = f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control'

  .row
    .col-xs-12
      .form-group
        = label_tag :images, 'Images'
        = f.file_field :images, multiple: true, class: 'form-control'

  .row
    .col-xs-12.text-right
      = f.submit "Cancel", class: 'btn btn-default', data: { dismiss: "modal" }
      = f.submit "Save",  class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

It works fine on my development environment. But when running on heroku (production), it fails when clicking on "Save" (**note that I am using Devise and the login/signup works fine**), with this error:

> 2016-10-14T11:55:02.825234+00:00 app[web.1]: W, [2016-10-14T11:55:02.825168 #3]  WARN -- Can't verify CSRF token authenticity.
>
> 2016-10-14T11:55:02.825602+00:00 app[web.1]: I,
>   [2016-10-14T11:55:02.825555 #3]  INFO -- : Completed 422 Unprocessable
>   Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
>
> 2016-10-14T11:55:02.826511+00:00 app[web.1]: F,
>   [2016-10-14T11:55:02.826471 #3] FATAL -- :
>   ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken
>   (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):

**The thing is when I don't select an image, it works fine. So I think the problem might be with the image uploader**:

**models/product.rb**

```
class Product
  mount_uploaders :images, ProductImageUploader
  # more stuff...
end
```

**uploaders/product_image_uploader.rb**

```
class ProductImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

**initializers/carrier_wave.rb**

```
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.storage = :file
    config.enable_processing = false if Rails.env.test?
  end
else
  CarrierWave.configure do |config|
    config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'                        # required
    config.fog_credentials = {
      provider:              'AWS',
      aws_access_key_id:     ENV["AWS_KEY_ID"],
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV["AWS_KEY_SECRET"],
      region:                'us-west-2',                  # optional, defaults to 'us-east-1'
    }

    config.fog_directory = ENV['AWS_BUCKET']
    config.fog_public = true

    config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads"
  end
end
```

Another thing is that I tried to to a simple storage: :file in production, avoiding the S3 upload stuff, and it fails too.

Any idea?

**UPDATE!**

I added the **authenticity_token: true** in the form and it doesn't raise the exception I mentioned above. However, something weird is happening:

- When I don't select an image from the form, the POST is done remote:

> Processing by ProductsController#create as JS

- When I select an image in the form, the POST is not done remote:

> Processing by ProductsController#create as HTML

**UPDATE 2!**

This is the generated html for the form tag:

```
<form class="product-form" id="new_product" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/seller/products" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
  <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="SOME STUFF">     </form>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In form declaration, after `remote: true` add this `authenticity_token: true` like:

```
form_for product, url: url, method: :post, html: { class: 'product-form' }, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f|
```

Comment: I've tried that and it worked! But it causes the form to not doing a remote POST.

Comment: In fact, the request.format in the controller returns this text/html. Before adding the authenticity_token it was js, as I expected.

Comment: Rails degrades the remote form to HTML fallback when JS is disabled or switched off . Can you confirm that js is working on your page ?

Comment: I will have to dig a little bit about it. For now I can suggest to use **remotipart** gem.

Comment: Thanks @sajan, I will mark your answer as correct if you find the solution. Added a second update btw.

Comment: It seems this issue exists from a long time like from Rails 3 so this gem is made with that goal in mind. you should give it a try. https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart. Check this thread, it has the same issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/16436443/4587148

Comment: I marked your answer as the correct because I tried this gem and it works. Thanks for your help!